# Webpack manifest is not using gzip version from Amazon S3

Tags: symfony, webpack, webpack-encore

I'm using Symfony Webpack Encore for my assets. I create gzip 
files with the CompressionPlugin and load it on Amazon S3 with the S3Plugin. I'm not compressing all assets files, so I cannot change all file names with the "configureFilenames" option.
I need the .gz in the filename, because of that I set the encoding on the upload to the S3.

The manifest.json generated by the Symfony Webpack Encore, only references my original assets, and not the gzip versions.

```
Encore
    .addPlugin(new CompressionPlugin({
        test: /\.(js|css)$/,
        filename: '[path].gz[query]',
        minRatio: 0.8,
        algorithm: 'gzip',
        deleteOriginalAssets: false
}));

Encore
    .addPlugin(new S3Plugin({
        s3Options: {
            ...
        },
        s3UploadOptions: {
            Bucket: '...',
            // Here we set the Content-Encoding header for all the gzipped files to 'gzip'
            ContentEncoding(fileName) {
                if (/\.gz/.test(fileName)) {
                    return 'gzip';
                }
            },
        },
    }));
```

The generated manifest.json looks like this:

```
{
  "build/main.css": "/build/main.fcbbf369.css",
  "build/main.js": "/build/main.d2286d33.js",
  "build/main.fcbbf369.css.gz": "/build/main.fcbbf369.css.gz",
  "build/main.d2286d33.js.gz": "/build/main.d2286d33.js.gz",
}
```

but it should look like that:

```
{
  "build/main.css": "/build/main.fcbbf369.css.gz",
  "build/main.js": "/build/main.d2286d33.js.gz"
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? Having kind of the same troubles.